# C#: Generics syntax question

Tags: c#, generics

What's the syntax to require T also be IComparable in this class definition?

```
public class EditItems<T> : Form
```

Comment: As a side note, generics and the VS designer don't usually play nice together.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. (It's better in VB since - unlike C# - the generic type is just used *after* it has been declared)

Comment: @Dario I'm not sure how it's better in VB... I've always had major problems using UI elements that are open generics in both VB and C#.

Comment: @Taylor L -- you're spot on there.  I had to edit the Designer file as well.

Comment: @Joseph: Oh, I just referred to the VS-Intellisense (not the UI - designer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class EditItems<T> : Form where T : IComparable
```

Answer (score 11):

You *can* use just `where T : IComparable` as shown by other answers. I find it's typically more helpful to constrain it with:

```
public class EditItems<T> : Form where T : IComparable<T>
```

That says it has to be a type which is comparable with itself.

For one thing, for value types this avoids boxing. For another, it means you're less likely to try to compare two values which aren't *really* comparable.

Comment: Not asked for but still true ;-)

Comment: The generic version is more type-safe, but if you want something akin to contravariance in the IComparable implementation you can only use the non-generic version, until C#4 comes out

Comment: I wondered if anyone would catch the IComparable<T>... I actually picked it because it would be an interface everyone would know so I could focus the question on the syntax (I'm not *really* using IComparable).  Thanks for the thorough response though!

Answer (score 4):

```
public class EditItems<T> : Form where T : IComparable
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a **type constraint** (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(VS.80).aspx)):

```
public class EditItems<T> : Form where T : IComparable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class EditItems<T> : Form where T : IComparable
{...}
```